# Refer to customized `enumerate` counter

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, counters, enumitem

### Background

I'm typesetting a list of conditions for a certain mathematical object. There are three conditions. Later on I wish to provide an equivalent condition for the third. Therefore, it would be nice to have this kind of numbering:

> c) condition 1
>
> b) condition 2
>
> c) condition 3

while later on there would be

> c') condition 3 (alternative)

My idea was to use a `\label{c}` for the original condition and write

```
\item[\ref{c}]\label{c-prime} ...
```

and it hoping it would be able to refer to c') this way. But `\ref{c-prime}` results in the number of the definition, not in the enumerate counter.

### Solution

I've got a solution, based on a hard-coded starting point for the counter and fixed layout. Using [`enumitem`](http://pkg.ctan.org/enumitem) I can write

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*'),ref=(\alph*'),start=3]
```

and everything works smoothly

### Question

There are some drawbacks:

- I have to hand pick the starting point for the counter, rendering it impossible to automatically change the ordering;
- the formatting for labels and references is hard-coded, if I change the global format I still have to adapt it locally.

What can I do to make this more flexible?

I am aware this is a rather academic question as it already works, but I'm curious

Comment: A "costumized" counter is one with a costume on?

Comment: No, it's one who has according to Oxford dictionary been "modified to suit a particular individual or task."

Comment: I tried to generalize this to having altconditions in two different places within my LaTeX document, but am having problems getting it to work: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/221020/multiple-altconditions-within-latex-document

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `enumitem` package gives you lots more—you can create `enumerate`-like list environments and set their format globally.  Then you can use a counter to save the value of the current item to feed to `start` later on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for blind text
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{conditions}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{altconditions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[conditions]{label=\alph*),ref=(\alph*)}
\setlist[altconditions]{label=\alph*$'$),ref=(\alph*$'$)}
\newcounter{favoritecondition}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{conditions}
\item condition 1
\item condition 2
\item condition 3\label{c}\setcounter{favoritecondition}{\value{conditionsi}}
\item condition 4
\end{conditions}

\lipsum[2]

An alternative to condition \ref{c} is

\begin{altconditions}[start=\value{favoritecondition}]
\item\label{c-prime} condition 3 alternative 
\end{altconditions}

We leave as an exercise to the reader that \ref{c} and \ref{c-prime} are equivalent.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer; the key is the line `\setcounter{favoritecondition}{\arabic{conditionsi}` although I think `\value` would strictly be better than `\arabic` here (even though both work).

Comment: @Will Robertson: I agree with your opinion but I couldn't get `\value` to work for me.  But I just made the change in my copy and it worked fine, so I must have been doing something else wrong.  I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! If you can help, I tried modifying this code to allow for altconditions in two different places within the document, and I can't quite get it to work: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/221020/multiple-altconditions-within-latex-document