# Multiple Altconditions within LaTeX Document

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, lists, environments, enumerate

The question refers to [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6360/refer-to-customized-enumerate-counter) and trying to modify the code to support multiple `altconditions` in my document.

The problem is to allow two sets of alternative conditions within the same document. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,enumitem}

% THEOREM Environments
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}



\newlist{zfcaltconditions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[zfcaltconditions]{label=\textbf{ZFC.\arabic*$'$},ref=\textbf{ZFC.\arabic*}$'$}
\newcounter{zfcpairing}

\newlist{conditions}{enumerate}{2}
\newlist{sigmaaltconditions}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[conditions]{label=\textbf{$\Sigma$\arabic*},ref=\textbf{$\Sigma$\arabic*}}
\setlist[sigmaaltconditions]{label=\textbf{$\Sigma$\arabic*$'$},ref=\textbf{$\Sigma$\arabic*}$'$}
\newcounter{sigmaaltconditions}
\newcounter{sigma3condition}
\newcounter{sigma4condition}

\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}[before=\itshape,font=\normalfont,label=\textbf{ZFC.\arabic*}, series=zfc]
    \item (Axiom 1 goes here)
    \item \label{zfcpairing} \setcounter{zfcpairing}{\value{zfcpairing}} (Axiom 2 goes here)
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{remark}
    We could begin with a weaker statement:
    \begin{zfcaltconditions}[start=\value{zfcpairing},before=\itshape,font=\normalfont]
      \item\label{zfcpairingalternative} (Axiom 2' goes here)
    \end{zfcaltconditions}
    End of remark. 
  \end{remark}

  \begin{enumerate}[resume,before=\itshape,font=\normalfont,label=\textbf{ZFC.\arabic*}]
    \item (Axiom 3 goes here)
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{definition}
    Let $\Omega$ be a set. A $\Sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ satisfies the following 4 properties:
    \begin{conditions}
    \item (Property 1 goes here)
    \item (Property 2 goes here)
    \item (Property 3 goes here)
       \label{algebraofsetsunions}\setcounter{sigma3condition}{\value{sigmaaltconditions}}
    \item (Property 4 goes here)  \label{algebraofsetscountableunions}\setcounter{sigma4condition}{\value{sigmaaltconditions}}
    \end{conditions}
  \end{definition}

  \begin{remark}
    By De Morgan's Laws, property \ref{algebraofsetsunions} is equivalent to
    \begin{sigmaaltconditions}[start=\value{sigma3condition}]
      \item\label{algebraofsetsintersections} (Property 3' goes here)
    \end{sigmaaltconditions}

    Similarly, property \ref{algebraofsetscountableunions} is equivalent to
    \begin{sigmaaltconditions}[start=\value{sigma4condition}]
      \item\label{algebraofsetscountableintersections} (Property 4' goes here)
    \end{sigmaaltconditions}
  \end{remark}
\end{document}
```

The output should give

```
ZFC.1
ZFC.2
ZFC.2'
ZFC.3
```

and

```
Σ1
Σ2
Σ3
Σ4
Σ3'
Σ4'
```

Instead, we see

```
ZFC.1
ZFC.2
ZFC.0'
ZFC.3
```

and

```
Σ1
Σ2
Σ3
Σ4
Σ0'
Σ0'
```

How can the code be modified to produce the desired results?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Ah! I didn't think of that! I was trying to spare everybody all the packages and stuff at the beginning because I didn't think it was relevant. But you're right! I've added them now, is this right?

Comment: Well, *minimal* is the key. Cut it down to the least amount of code showing the problem. e.g., `geometry`, `pgf`, `hyperref`, and others could be removed and the problem would likely persist. Same with any custom command definitions you have that aren't in the problem areas.

Comment: See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for the canonical advice on this.

Comment: Please verify that the document I added to the top of your question shows the same errors you had before, and that those errors are the problem you're experiencing. In addition to cutting out several dozen lines that weren't showing errors, I had to modify some of the `\begin` and `\end` lines for the `conditions` and `conditions2` environments to get this to build at all. If the `\setcounter` lines are truly the problem you're running into, please remove the rest of your document from the question so others can more clearly see the problem. That's much closer to a MWE you can get help with.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your edit. Unfortunately the code you made omits the problem, which is trying to get altconditions to work in 2 different places. I might not have been clear in my question. But the effect I'm trying to achieve is to have ZFC axioms with the first `altcondition` being ZFC.4 followed by a ZFC.4', and then a section on measure theory where the second `altcondition` is to have Σ3 and Σ4 followed by Σ3' and Σ4'. I edited the question to make this more more clear. I hope this helps... Thanks again!

Comment: That is not at all minimal. *Just* the stuff which is *necessary* to produce the problem, whatever it is. (I'm not at all clear and I guess I'm not the only one.) ***Your current code CANNOT be compiled.*** Please *check* your code before uploading it.

Comment: Please verify that my version of your question reflects the question you wish to ask. If not, you can simply rollback the changes to the previous version. I had to modify things quite a bit to get it to build at all. I then cut most of it out in an attempt to focus on the issue, as I understand it. I've put a warning at the top so people don't spend time on this without verifying that I've understood. If my rewrite does reflect your intentions, edit the question to remove that warning. If not, rollback my changes completely.

Comment: @cfr, you got it. My sincere apologies that my question was not clear from the beginning. I'm glad that we finally have a MWE which compiles and is very focused on the problem. In the future when uploading code, I'll be sure to follow the example you have modeled. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\setcounter{zfcpairing}{\value{zfcpairing}}` is really superfluous. Instead, you need to assign to the `zfcpairing` counter the `\value` of `enumi` - that's just because you're in the first level (`i`) of the `enumerate` environment. Similarly, for the `conditions` list, the counter running with each `\item` is `conditionsi` (first level of the `conditions` list)... so I've used `\value{conditionsi}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,enumitem}

% THEOREM Environments
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\newlist{zfcaltconditions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[zfcaltconditions]{label=\textbf{ZFC.\arabic*$'$},ref=\textbf{ZFC.\arabic*}$'$}
\newcounter{zfcpairing}

\newlist{conditions}{enumerate}{2}
\newlist{sigmaaltconditions}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[conditions]{label=\textbf{$\Sigma$\arabic*},ref=\textbf{$\Sigma$\arabic*}}
\setlist[sigmaaltconditions]{label=\textbf{$\Sigma$\arabic*$'$},ref=\textbf{$\Sigma$\arabic*}$'$}
\newcounter{sigmaaltconditions}
\newcounter{sigma3condition}
\newcounter{sigma4condition}

\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}[before=\itshape,font=\normalfont,label=\textbf{ZFC.\arabic*},series=zfc]
    \item (Axiom 1 goes here)
    \item \label{zfcpairing} \setcounter{zfcpairing}{\value{enumi}} (Axiom 2 goes here)
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{remark}
    We could begin with a weaker statement:
    \begin{zfcaltconditions}[start=\value{zfcpairing},before=\itshape,font=\normalfont]
      \item\label{zfcpairingalternative} (Axiom 2' goes here)
    \end{zfcaltconditions}
    End of remark. 
  \end{remark}

  \begin{enumerate}[resume,before=\itshape,font=\normalfont,label=\textbf{ZFC.\arabic*}]
    \item (Axiom 3 goes here)
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{definition}
    Let $\Omega$ be a set. A $\Sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ satisfies the following 4 properties:
    \begin{conditions}
    \item (Property 1 goes here)
    \item (Property 2 goes here)
    \item (Property 3 goes here)
      \label{algebraofsetsunions}\setcounter{sigma3condition}{\value{conditionsi}}
    \item (Property 4 goes here)
      \label{algebraofsetscountableunions}\setcounter{sigma4condition}{\value{conditionsi}}
    \end{conditions}
  \end{definition}

  \begin{remark}
    By De Morgan's Laws, property \ref{algebraofsetsunions} is equivalent to
    \begin{sigmaaltconditions}[start=\value{sigma3condition}]
      \item\label{algebraofsetsintersections} (Property 3' goes here)
    \end{sigmaaltconditions}

    Similarly, property \ref{algebraofsetscountableunions} is equivalent to
    \begin{sigmaaltconditions}[start=\value{sigma4condition}]
      \item\label{algebraofsetscountableintersections} (Property 4' goes here)
    \end{sigmaaltconditions}
  \end{remark}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! In the future, if I do this in a third location in my document, I think I'll be able to figure out how, thanks to your example. Any suggestions as to what to read if I want to understand better what the part in the header is doing? For example, what the `{2}` in the `\newlist{conditions}{enumerate}{2}` means, or what `series=zfc` does? Would love to understand this better. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @EthanAlvaree: `\newlist{<listA>}{<listB>}{<num>}` creates a list `<listA>` that is based on `<listB>` and has at most `<num>` levels. That is, you can only nest `<num>` version of `<listA>` inside one another. `series=<name>` "stores" the specific settings for that list so that later on you can reuse it. All of this is contained in the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

Comment: I just discovered the extremely helpful `series*=<name>`, thanks to you. I hope this question's title is sufficient for others with the same question to find (if not, please suggest a better title and I will gladly edit my question). Thanks again for your help!